# C++ syntax, simple arithmetic function variable result undeclared?

Tags: c++

I'm working on C++ and I'm confused as to why this function won't work. Coming from Ruby, this should be a breeze but I can't seem to get this to work? Any thoughts on my syntax? the error I get is this?

```
sum.c: In function 'sum':
sum.c:7:5: error: 'result' undeclared (first use in this function)
sum.c:7:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it a   
ppears in
```

Here is my simple function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int a, int b) {
  // Write your code here
  // To print results to the standard output you can use printf()
  // Example: printf("%s", "Hello world!");
  result = a + b;
  printf(result);
}
```

I don't understand wat the last error line is saying to me.

Comment: You are working on C++, but you use a C extension? Also, I don't see any code that would indicate this is not just C.

Comment: `int result = a + b; printf("Result = %d\n");`

Comment: Well, it's no wonder why I had such a hard time. You're absolutely right. Noob mistake.

Comment: You should be using `printf` with a format string as the first parameter, not a the actual data to print.

Comment: Coming from Ruby, you'll probably find that very few things are breezes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually didn't **declare** the `result` variable in your function (but just trying to use it), change your code to

```
void sum(int a, int b) {
  int result = a + b;
//^^^
  printf("result = %d\n",result);
}
```

You probably wanted to have a `sum()` function declared/defined like this

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

and call it with `printf()`

```
  printf("result = %d\n",sum(5,12));
```

If you want to do it, using c++ idiomatic syntax

```
#include <iostream>
// ...
std::cout << sum(5,12) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks you guys, it turns out I got C and C++ mixed up in the tutorial I was using. Noob mistake.

Comment: @DanRubio OK, along all your misconceptions about c and c++ output operations, this answer should serve you quite well solving your problems! You might consider accepting it ...

Answer (score 3):

The error message is clear enough: variable result is undeclared, its type is unknown. You can write either

```
void sum(int a, int b) {
  // Write your code here
  // To print results to the standard output you can use printf()
  // Example: printf("%s", "Hello world!");
  int result = a + b;
  printf( "%d\n", result );
}
```

or

```
void sum(int a, int b) {
  // Write your code here
  // To print results to the standard output you can use printf()
  // Example: printf("%s", "Hello world!");
  auto result = a + b;
  printf( "%d\n", result );
}
```

or you could write the function without variable result

```
void sum(int a, int b) {
  // Write your code here
  // To print results to the standard output you can use printf()
  // Example: printf("%s", "Hello world!");
  printf( "%d\n", a + b );
}
```

Take into account how function printf is used in the code above.